# Is there a way to integrate Microsoft Bot Framework handoff to Salesforce Live agent

Tags: salesforce, botframework, livechat, handoff

I am not able to find a way to connect bot to a live agent.

I tried with MS dynamics 365, that seems to be a paid version, So i have decided to try with salesforce live chat integration, Is there a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This Project https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library , should help you to get started